# Varchar2(CHAR) always in PLSQL?

Tags: oracle, plsql

If the DB is using `utf8` as charset does it make sense to use varchar2 with byte semantics?

Consider a variable:

```
l_str varchar2(10 BYTE);
```

If I later assign values to it based on a query that will return the contents of a `10 char` column I have no way of knowing how much bytes those characters will take, in `utf8` that might be more than one byte per character.

So when using a multibyte character set shouldn't I always use the following?

```
l_str varchar2(10 CHAR);
```

Or to put it another way, is there any reason why you should use `varchar2(10 byte)` or `varchar2(10)` in PLSQL?

EDIT: The only reason I can think of for using `byte` is if you know for sure how many bytes the characters stored will need. So in this case you will allocate less memory.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the character set I think you just end up only getting half the space you might expect with a more restrictive set for instance. This is confirmed by the documentation

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14251/adfns_sqltypes.htm#sthref367

id VARCHAR2(32 BYTE)

The id column contains only single-byte data, up to 32 bytes.

name VARCHAR2(32 CHAR)

The name column contains data in the database character set. If the database character set allows multibyte characters, then the 32 characters can be stored as more than 32 bytes.

Comment: `id VARCHAR2(32 BYTE)` will give a problem if you move the DB to a character encoding like `utf16`.

Answer (score 1):

I have AL32UTF8 charset with Oracle 11g.  Oracle stores byte and char data with different lenght.  e.g.--

```
create table t1(aa varchar2(1));
create table t2(aa varchar2(1 char));
```

Now execute--

```
select * from ALL_TAB_COLUMNS where table_name in ('T1','T2');
```

Check the `DATA_LENGTH` column where for byte datatype, it has 1 as value and for char it has 4 as value.

You may follow [this link](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/statviews_2094.htm) for ALL_TAB_COLUMNS columns description.